# Position Absolute how to make it center no matter what screen resolution it is viewed in?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am having a problem here, i have much of my elements inside a `<div>` being `position:absolute`. And it all seems good until i changed its resolution i realised that the elements is not positioned on the center.

here is an example code for one of elements.

```
p img {
    position: absolute;
}
#contentback p img {
    top: 300px;
    left: 250px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: `margin: auto; width: 500px;`

Comment: Does not seems to be working. Its as though the img is being stuck onto the page if i restore down the window it will only eat up the right spaces instead of the equally on both left and right

Comment: @user15915802 That style should be applied to a parent, block-level element, not the image itself.

Comment: so i have to apply it to #contentback in my case right? But it still isnt working.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 margin:auto;
```

If you still wanna adjust it,

```
margin-left:x%;
margin-right:x%;
```

You can change `x`

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `width: xxpx` and also use `margin:auto;`

**Updated**

remove the `left: xxpx` to make it `center` align.

Comment: thn do i nid to remove the left: xxpx;?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not possible with `absolute` positioning. Such positioning just takes the element out of the body's normal flow, and it cannot be automatically centered. For that, you have to use `relative` positioning. The element must have a fixed width, otherwise the browser will never know how much side space should be left as margin. Then, apply `margin: auto`. Table positioning will also achieve this, but it's whole lot complex. And mind you, you cannot position elements centrally in the vertical direction by this method!

Answer (score 0):

the best technique that I know for centering an element that is positioned absolutely:

```
.element {
width:500px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-250px;
}
```

this method requires that the object have a fixed width. but it has worked very well for me.